# Possible lossy conversion from long to int, JAVA

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, long-integer

I am trying to pass long value to the method and use it there to create a Long Array. However,
I am getting "possible lossy conversion from long to int" error while creating an array

```
long[] array = new long[n];
```

although I have not used any integers values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = input.nextLong();

    System.out. although("result is " + n + " is " + testing(n));
}

private static long testing(long n){
    long[] array = new long[n];

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just trying to understand the error that I had on line       long[] array = new long[n];   the rest was just to demo the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array dimensions can only be `int` types. The compiler is expecting that type but you are passing in a `long` type. You could change the argument type being passed in to an `int` and the make the corresponding changes.

For completeness, here is what the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) says about variables in an array

> they are referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative **integer** index values.